# minidlna + OpenVPN = Can't see DLNA server on VPN

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, dlna

I've got OpenVPN (tunnel, not bridged) and minidlna servers running on my Ubuntu 14.04 PC.  Each one works individually (as in the VPN works, I can connect and browse samba shares and internet traffic goes through the VPN; the minidlna server works with client connected to my LAN) but when my client (android) connects to the VPN via 3G/4G, it can't see the minidlna server.  I edited the interfaces line of the `/etc/minidlna.conf` file `network_interface=eth0,tun0` but that didn't do the trick.  I read somewhere that this may have something to do with broadcasts and require adding to `iptables` rules but there weren't any specifics.  What must I do in order to make this work?

IPv4 forwarding is allowed in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and I've added the following to iptables already as per [this OpenVPN guide to browse the web securely over public wifi](https://www.tinfoilsecurity.com/blog/dont-get-pwned-on-public-wifi-use-your-own-vpn-tutorial-guide-how-to) :

```
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

and I made sure that the `iptables` changes survive restarts by using [iptables-persistent](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/iptables-persistent/) (which is available for Ubuntu 14.04 from a default repository, even though I didn't see it listed on the linked web page at the time of writing).

**Edit**
I tried going from `dev tun` to `dev tap` but the OpenVPN app doesn't support it. 
I also read about something called GRE. Can OpenVPN support that?

Comment: I believe you do need TAP to have multicast on OpenVPN.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem than you, here's my solution :

in the conf file of the minidlna, you have the argument "listen_ip" which is commented. Uncomment it, and write the adresse of your vpn server on the interface tun0. In your case it seems that it's 10.8.0.1.
Restart the minidlna server, it should work when you're outside the network, connected through vpn.

WARNING : by doing this, your minidlna will not be visible insed your local network. I'm looking for a solution here : [MiniDLNa local AND over openvpn](https://superuser.com/questions/987023/minidlna-local-and-over-openvpn)

Answer (score 1):

See here [openvpn-with-upnp-support-in-10-minutes](http://web.archive.org/web/20190204161705/https://wiki.celogeek.com/pages/Tutorials:OpenVPN_with_uPNP_support_in_10_minutes) about how to set this up for UPnP. (I'm not sure how DLNA fits into this). I managed to get this to work with Android client and OpenVPN.

The critical bit seems to be the [`upnpd` provided by linux-igd package](http://linux-igd.sourceforge.net/). It bridges the VPN and the "local" network somehow.

Comment: The link is dead, could you please provide an update, or copy the relevant part to your answer?

Comment: @Petr Fixed the link. I found the page on the Wayback Machine (love that project) I had totally forgotten about this thing. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I decided that UPnP/DLNA via OpenVPN was not the way to go.  I instead installed apache2, h.264 and linked the folder containing the media I want to stream like this

```
cd /var/html/www
ln -s /path/to/media myfoldername
```

So now when I connect to my client to the VPN (after deleting the default `index.html` file), I can point a web browser at the local IP of the the server and it pops up with a directory called `myfoldername` that I can browse for the media that I want to stream.  Clicking a file opens the h.264 player and streams the video.

**Edit**

And then I found Plex Media Server. This seems like the best solution. All I had to do was allow my VPN subnet in Plex and now I can use the Web interface remotely on my phone to stream all my media, after adding the media to the Plex library of course.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but I am posting my solution in case it helps somebody else.

If you give in a terminal of the machine running `minidlna` the following command:

```
sudo netstat -tuwanp | grep "Proto\|dlna"
```

you will get something like the following result:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address                               Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8200                                0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      your-pid/minidlnad
udp        0      0 239.255.255.250:1900                        0.0.0.0:*                           your-pid/minidlnad
udp        0      0 your-vpn-server-ip:your-random-port         0.0.0.0:*                           your-pid/minidlnad
udp        0      0 your-minidlna-server-ip:your-random-port    0.0.0.0:*                           your-pid/minidlnad
```

According to https://extremeportal.force.com/ExtrArticleDetail?an=000091058 the address `239.255.255.250` is used for UPnP (Universal Plug and Play)/SSDP (Simple Service Discovery Protocol). So, we must add this address to the VPN routing configuration in order to be possible for the VPN clients to discover the DLNA service.

- For `OpenVPN` this can be done by pushing the config to all clients through the server config:

  ```
  push "route 239.255.255.250 255.255.255.255 vpn_gateway"
  ```

  or you can add the corresponding routing config to every client individually.
- For `WireGuard` this can be done by adding the IP in each peer's config file:

  ```
  AllowedIPs = your-existing-allowed-ip-list, 239.255.255.250/32
  ```

After changing your VPN configuration:

- restart the VPN service
- reboot the machine running `minidlna` service (Just restarting the `minidlna` service didn't work for me.)
- connect your VPN client and give it some time to discover the DLNA service