# MiniDLNa local AND over openvpn

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, raspberry-pi, dlna

I have a raspberry pi with a minidlna server and an openvpn server.

When I'm on my local network I have access to my DLNA without problems.

When I'm outside (cellular or another wifi) I connect my device to the openvpn, and if I want to see my miniDLNA, I must change the parameter listen_ip to the ip of the vpn (which is 10.8.0.1), instead of the ip of my rpi on the local network.

So, actually it's not possible to see my miniDLNA from my local network AND from outside at the same time.

Is there a way to run my miniDLNA both on local and external network ?

Thanks !

EDIT : I also tried with the ip 0.0.0.0, but my DLNA is not seeing from outside.

EDIT2 : running 2 instances resolves the problem.

Comment: Could you post your 2 working minidlna.conf files and/or CLI options for the 2 instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two immediate solutions:

- Run Bridged OpenVPN: This is tricky to set up, much more difficult that regular NAT mode in my opinion
- Run two DLNA daemons, one on 10. and one on 192.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edit my original post, why doesn't it work with 0.0.0.0 ? Also, how can you do to run 2 DLNA daemons ?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 = Me, 10.8.0.1 = Me, 192...= Me. 0.0.0.0 = Everyone I dont know (AKA nothing to do with me). The listener wont work on that, its used for routing, Here's a guide to run two: https://spremi.wordpress.com/2014/06/30/minidlna-multiple-instances/

Comment: It seems strange, especially when I read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0 . According to this link, in this case we're in the context of server right ? Thank you for the link, I'll try later and post my feedback.